# Blazor WASM Authentication with two different OIDC Providers (Azure AD, Auth0)

Tags: blazor

I can't work out or find documentation on how to have *two different* OIDC providers working in a Blazor WASM app. All the "recipes", docs, and libraries show how to use a single provider with a load of MSAL OIDC/OAUTH magic happening out of sight in components and javascript.

Can anyone point me to a resource or example that goes beyond the MS Learn tutorials or indicate how I can have a user choose between an Identity Provider. The IdP just needs to return an id_token. I know I can go through the source code, I'm just hoping there is an intermediate stage between magic and source code.

I thought I might be able to pass a scheme to `RemoteAuthenticatorView` but I don't think that is possible. I'm also exploring if manually setting the `RemoteAuthenticationApplicationPathsOptions` to point to the specific IdP as a way forward.

Any other ideas are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change `RemoteAuthenticatorView` you need to change the login page writting your own insted of using the standard "authentication/login" url.

You have to create a login Blazor page

```
@page "/login"
@using BlazorApp1.Shared;
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
  
@foreach (var item in identityProviders)
{
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => ExternalLogin(item)">@item.DisplayName</button>
}

@code {
    List<IdentityProvider> identityProviders = new List<IdentityProvider>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        identityProviders.Add(new IdentityProvider { AuthenticationScheme = "oidc", DisplayName = "Google" });
        identityProviders.Add(new IdentityProvider { AuthenticationScheme = "oidc-idserver", DisplayName = "Azure AD" });

    }
    private void ExternalLogin(IdentityProvider schema)
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo("/pages/external?returnurl=/&schema=" + schema.AuthenticationScheme, true);

    }
}
```

Then on server you can create a standard Asp.Net Web Page to handle the login request, get the schema and redirect to the correct Identity Provider:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public class ExternalModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
            
        public ExternalModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGetAsync(string returnUrl, string schema)
        {
            returnUrl = (returnUrl == null) ? "/" : returnUrl;

            if (schema != "")
            {                
                var redirectUrl = Url.Page("./External", pageHandler: "Callback", values: new { returnUrl });
                var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(schema, redirectUrl);
                return new ChallengeResult(schema, properties);                
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                return new EmptyResult();
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            if (remoteError != null)
            {
                var errorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                var errorMessage = "Error loading external login information.";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
            var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
        }     
    }
```

This is an incomplete example but to understand the idea